# List the subnets shared to service project in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-vpc

I would like to list only the subnets that are shared to a service project in GCP.

For example:

**Host project name:** *host-project-prod*

**subnets in host project:** *host-project-sn-01,host-project-sn-02,host-project-sn-03*

**Service project Name:** *service-project-prod*

**shared subnet to service project:** *host-project-sn-02*

Tried: `gcloud compute networks subnets list-usable --project=<host-project-id>`  using this command, it lists all the subnets in the hostproject.

In my case I just want to know the subnets in the service project (that is host-project-sn-02)